# C# method definition with lambda notation

Tags: c#

I noticed the following notation for defining an extension method. This kind of syntax must be new since it is not recognized in Visual Studio 2013 but only in VS2015

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMembersInAssembly(
        this Assembly asm, string memberName) =>
            from type in asm.GetTypes()
            from ms in type.GetMember(memberName, MemberTypes.All,
                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance)
            select ms;
```

I believe that the equivalent class syntax would be

```
public static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetMembersInAssembly1(
 this Assembly asm, string memberName) {
 return from type in asm.GetTypes()
 from ms in type.GetMember(memberName, MemberTypes.All,
 BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
 BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance)
 select ms;
}
```

I would like to ask what are the semantics of this new syntax?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx look for expression-bodied

Comment: why did someone vote to close this? they checked "off topic , not about programming ? "

Comment: @ScottSelby: I voted to close as off-topic for asking for a tutorial or off-site resource. Arturo's comment pretty much validates my reason (an MSDN article exists). I understand it sort of teeters on being on-topic.

Comment: There are other stack sites more suited for questions asking for resources.  Software Recommendations, Code Review, etc.

Comment: I see your point , I think question should be edited to just ask for an explanation , not a third party site that has an explanation

Comment: @Ryios FYI, Code Review's purpose is not to provide resources, it is to review real, working code for improvements.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because there is no question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I believe that the equivalent class syntax would be

Yes, it's the same, this is a new feature in *C# 6.0* called *Expression-Bodied*, is a syntactic sugar that allows define methods and properties where the body is defined by the given expression.

For example:

```
public string Property 
{
    get 
    {
        return "some value";
    }
}

public void PrintLine(string line)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Can be written like:

```
public string Property => "some value";

public void PrintLine(string line) => Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think your equivalent class isn't right. That kind of syntax is LINQ query.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx

Comment: no - OP obivously knows what LINQ is , and was asking for specifically extension methods with LINQ function in the definition